# Query Peformance for Tags

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I’m creating a system, backed by a MySQL database, and a question appeared about what would be the best practice.

I have a “group“ entity, which have zero or more "tags".

The tables could be represented by:

```
Groups
+-------+--------+
| id    | name   |
+-------+--------+
|     1 | Group1 |
|     2 | Hey Guy|
|     3 | Chacko |
|     4 | Dropo  |
+-------+--------+

GroupsTags
+-------+--------+
|idGroup| idTag  |
+-------+--------+
|     1 |      1 |
|     1 |      2 |
|     2 |      1 |
+-------+--------+

Tags
+-------+--------+
| id    | name   |
+-------+--------+
|     1 | Health |
|     2 | Happy  |
+-------+--------+
```

The system, during the “group” registration, I want that to autocomplete every key press, showing the most popular tags, similar to StackOverflow. In other words, I have to do a query at database for each letter type, order by popularity.

What solution is the best?

What is the best?

```
select count(*) as qt,Tags.nome from GroupsTags
inner join Tags
on Tags.id = GroupsTags.idTag
where Tags.name like "phrase%"
group by GroupsTags.idTag
order by qt desc
```

or, save in the Tags table, the amount of times it was used. Like this

```
Tags
+-------+--------+--------+
| id    | name   | qtUsed |
+-------+--------+--------+
|     1 | Health |      2 |
|     2 | Happy  |      1 |
+-------+--------+--------+

select * from Tags where name like "phrase%" order by qtUsed desc
```

I wonder if it is really needed to put the number of times that the tag was used to get a better performance. Would it be a bad practice ?

Comment: I would suggest not necessarily doing every key press, but maybe in a `setInterval()` loop. Check every 200ms only if the input has changed, or whatever interval seems natural.

Comment: Your question is sort of down to your specific use case though. If traffic won't be overwhelmingly high and you find the right querying interval, and your tables are indexed (the FK's defined) you may get away with the join query. If as you scale the performance isn't meeting your need, then you can build the logic to keep track of `qtUsed`. More coding up front and maintenance for better performance later, or careful schema design up front saving code.

Comment: Unless you expect to have a HUGE number of tags with very low cardinality in the first several letters of the tags (i.e. you have groups of tags with similar first 4 or 5 letters), I don't see what value you are going to get in trying to place any order on the tags.  In most cases, an autocomplete will be able to differentiate down to a handful of options by the time you have typed 4 or 5 characters, and you usually don't want to even start triggering the autocomplete lookup until you have 2-3 characters typed in anyway. Is it really worth the trouble to add any popularity-based sorting logic?

Comment: To launch a DOS attack on the database would involve having my two years old play with my keyboard while registering at your site. I agree with the above comments relook your design a little.